# avoid initial load for " auto_refresh = setInterval "

Tags: ajax, jquery

if you see below code "left-profile-load.php" will load every 9 seconds but the problem is i need to wait 9 second also for initial load.

So how to avoid this problem(initial load) ?

```
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$('#preview_project').fadeOut("slow").load('left-profile-load.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 9000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define a function:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var load = function() {
    $('#preview_project').fadeOut("slow").load('left-profile-load.php').fadeIn("slow");    
};
```

and then:

```
var auto_refresh = window.setInterval(load, 9000);
load();
```

or simply use `setTimeout` with an anonymous function:

```
(function() {
    $('#preview_project').fadeOut('slow').load('left-profile-load.php').fadeIn('slow');
    window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 9000);
})();
```

Notice how `arguments.callee` is used here to obtain a reference to the containing anonymous function in order to achieve a recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

load the left-profile-load.php when the document ready at first

```
$(function(){
      $('#preview_project').fadeOut("slow").load('left-profile-load.php').fadeIn("slow")
})
```